# Script stops working after .load()

Tags: jquery

I'm currently running into an issue where once I delete a row from my sql table via php, I want the table to refresh to show the five results as opposed to showing four results due to a deletion. So what I managed to do was pass the message to my sql database and then use jQuery to refresh the div box. However once I refresh the div via .load() the controls stop working.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve8srkmz/1/) I wasn't able to completely replicate my issue however what occurs is I am no longer able to click my 'settings' widget, the jquery stops working once it reinitializes the div box.

I apologize for not being able to show a proper example but I hope the JSFiddle will help you understand what I am saying.

**What stops working is the code below:**

```
$(".controlTd").click(function () {
  $(this).children(".settingsIcons").toggleClass("display"); 
  $(this).children(".settingsIcon").toggleClass("openIcon"); 
});
```

**Note:**
The console log displays no errors when it reloads the div box and I try clicking the settings widget to delete a row.

**Actual page**

```
<div id="softLeft">
<div id="leftBox">

  <table class="flatTable">
      <tr class="headingTr">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filled='0' ORDER BY date ASC, name ASC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo (
    '<tr class="mshift '.$row['code'].'">
    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
    <td class="controlTd">
        <div class="settingsIcons">
            <span class="settingsIcon"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nnzONel.png" alt="X" /></span>
            <span class="settingsIcon" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;'.$row['code'].'&quot;)">Delete</span>
            <div class="settingsIcon" onclick="editRow(&quot;'.$row['code'].'&quot;)">Edit</div>
            <div class="settingsIcon" onclick="fillRow(&quot;'.$row['code'].'&quot;)">Fill</div>
        </div> 
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>)'
```

**file.php**

```
$code         = filter_var($_POST["code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$login        = $_SESSION['SESS_CONTROL_LOGIN'];

//proceed with PHP mysqli Query.

$qry = "DELETE FROM shifts WHERE code = '$code'";
//Check whether the query was successful or not
$result = @mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
if(!$result)
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => "Error! Could not delete data entry."));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Data entry removed.'));
    die($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was unable to receive an answer, I came up with an alternative. I emptied my table script onto a separate document and used jquery to load that content onto my div leftBox. On the table page I included the jquery that allows to manage the control options thus making sure that both the table and the script are initiated at the same pace, and I included an autorefresh on the page as well.

**Home.php**

```
  <div id="leftBox">

  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#leftBox').load('TableData.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
function deleteRow(code) {
        var proceed = true;
        if (proceed) {
            post_data = {'code': code};
            $.post('Delete.php', post_data, function (response) {
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
                } else {
                    output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
                }
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }
                else {
                    refreshTable();
                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();


                }
            }, 'json');
        }
    };
</script>
```

**TableData.php**

```
    <h2 style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);">Unfilled Shifts</h2>
    <table class="flatTable">
      <tr class="headingTr">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Caller</td>
        <td>Time In</td>
        <td>Time Out</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filled='0' ORDER BY date ASC, name ASC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo (
    '<tr class="mshift '.$row['code'].'">
    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
    <td class="controlTd">
        <div class="settingsIcons">
            <span class="settingsIcon"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nnzONel.png" alt="X" /></span>
            <span class="settingsIcon" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;'.$row['code'].'&quot;)">Delete</span>
            <div class="settingsIcon" onclick="editRow(&quot;'.$row['code'].'&quot;)">Edit</div>
            <div class="settingsIcon" onclick="fillRow(&quot;'.$row['code'].'&quot;)">Fill</div>
        </div> 
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".controlTd").click(function () {
  var span=$(this).children(".settingsIcons");
  span.toggleClass("display"); 
  span.children(".settingsIcon").toggleClass("openIcon"); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here!

```
$(this).children(".settingsIcon").toggleClass("openIcon");
```

Now span is not a direct child of td, hence you cannot use $(this).children(".settingsIcon").
You can do like this-

```
$(".controlTd").click(function () {
  var span=$(this).children(".settingsIcons");
  span.toggleClass("display"); 
  span.children(".settingsIcon").toggleClass("openIcon"); 
});
```

Comment: I've just tried this and to no avail! Once I delete the row and it loads the div via jquery I can no longer click the widget again! I pasted the clicking code into my console and it allowed me to click the widget until I deleted another row then it didn't work again.

Comment: @Josh I dont understand what you are trying to say, in ur fiddle, even the row is'nt deleted when delete is clicked, can you show your proper code, so we can find out what's the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).on('click', ".controlTd', function(){

  $(this).children(".settingsIcons").toggleClass("display"); 
  $(this).children(".settingsIcon").toggleClass("openIcon");
});
```

I guess the controls you are using or your code replace the .controlTd DOM element, and after that no event handler is attached to it. You can use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to solve this problem.

By the way, using 'this' in callback function is not a good idea, since 'this' will always point to root object in callback function, which is window. That is the reason your code will work the first time. There is no inheritance or closure for 'this' keyword.

Run this code in your console:

```
var myObj = {
    p1: 'fdsfds',
    func1: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(this === window);
        }, 100);
    }
};
myObj.func1();
```

Comment: Delegation is not working console points to the jquery file and indicates undefined.

Comment: sorry, I just updated my answer using on() to replace delegate(). It should work this time.

Comment: well i guess this refers to the object on which a method is being invoked and not the global window object. In the current case this refers to $(".controlTd"). reference- learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".controlTd").on('click', function(){
   $(this).children(".settingsIcons").toggleClass("display"); 
   $(this).children(".settingsIcon").toggleClass("openIcon"); 
});
```